# How to implement a collection view that will scroll based on the number of items provided (number count of physical items)?

Tags: swift, scrollview, uicollectionviewcell, collectionview

I've been struggling with the theoretical part of this issue and I couldn't find anything useful. So this is what Im trying to do

I'm writing an app for a grocery store. I want to implement a collection view (on the screen, only 4 items are displayed), when you click the more button under the 4 items (collection view cells), the collection view will load more items. However, I don't know the item count, as that has to be provided by the grocery store at execution time

How do I approach this?

I'm trying to have 3-4 collection views on the same screen, working exactly as I've described. So they are categories basically

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: Try a different approach. Those categories should be sections inside one collectionView, since they have the same kind of content.